# How to read response code from TcpClient

Tags: c#, tcpclient

I just wonder how to read Response code from TCP client? The sample codes are below.

```
var tcpClient = new TcpClient();
tcpClient.Connect(this.Settings.MailServer,  this.Settings.MailServerPort);


NetworkStream stream = tcpClient.GetStream();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stream > byte > String

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int bytesRead = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
response = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
Console.WriteLine(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

```
byte[] message = new byte[512];
int bytesRead;
bytesRead = stream.Read(message, 0, message.Length);
ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
Console.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
```